# how to get date in DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss:ssss using moment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I want know is there a way capture millisecond of current time using momentjs

The scenario i am working is storing user chat messages want to capture the time of message sent with milliseconds currently i am not sure how to do it

i am using mongodb with nodejs
 Mongoose schema is as shown below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var moment = require('moment');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        CatId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
        Name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        Description: String,
        Is_Active: Number,
        Db_Created_TimeStamp: { type: Date, default: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a') },
        Db_Updated_TimeStamp: { type: Date, default: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a') },
    }, { collection: "Categories" })
categorySchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
mongoose.model('Categories', categorySchema);
```

when i save the entry in the database is as shown below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a13fddf620d8e4ba85e476c"),
    "Is_Active" : NumberInt(1),
    "Description" : "spsss00ort",
    "Name" : "ssss",
    "CatId" : NumberInt(103),
    "Db_Updated_TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-11-21T10:19:37.000+0000"),
    "Db_Created_TimeStamp" : ISODate("2017-11-21T10:19:37.000+0000"),
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

looking for a way to capture millisecond also of the entry

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to store the time in milliseconds, anyways while creating the schema you can pass timestamps object which will create these two fields automatically.

```
var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
      CatId:{ type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
      Name : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      Description : String,
      Is_Active:Number
  },{ collection: "Categories",timestamps: { createdAt: 'Db_Created_TimeStamp' ,updatedAt:'Db_Updated_TimeStamp'} })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store timestamps, You just need to change the schema as

```
  Db_Created_TimeStamp:{type:Number,default: moment.utc().valueOf()},
  Db_Updated_TimeStamp:{type:Number,default: moment.utc().valueOf()},
```

This will store utc milliseconds to you db

Comment: DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss:ssss

Comment: I think you want to store the time in milliseconds, anyways while creating the schema you can pass timestamps object which will create the these two fields automatically.

Comment: i want the format in 
 
DD-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss:ssss where ssss is milliseconds